Joining two tables: Cannot join on Memo, OLE, or Hyperlink Object
I have 2 tables AudioInfo and Dev as shown below on MSAccess:
【AudioInfo】 has the following columns:



file_id (Long Text)
duration_sec (Number)




1_1
15



【Dev】 (short for Development Set) has the following columns:



sourceid (Long Text)
language (Long Text)




1_1
English



I want to create the following table when AudioInfo.file_id = Dev.sourceid.



file_id
language
duration_sec




1_1
English
15



I tried the following SQL query but results in an error:
SELECT Dev.sourceid, Dev.language, AudioInfo.file_id FROM Dev
INNER JOIN AudioInfo ON Dev.sourceid = AudioInfo.file_id;

This results in a pop up error message of: Cannot join on Memo, OLE, or Hyperlink Object (Dev.sourceid=AudioInfo.file_id);
Could someone correct the above SQL to get the result that I want.

SIDE NOTE
For additional information, when importing 【AudioInfo】 and 【Dev】 .tsv (tab separated value) text file using Import Text Wizard, I changed all Short Text field type to Long Text.
When Field Information: group box's Indexed field's value is Yes, changing the field type from 'Long Text` results in the following warning:
Changing field to Memo or OLE datatype requires removal of the specified index.

What is the field type of each of those fields?

Msg from MS Doc: A long strings in Access is considered a MEMO field, and it is an Access limitation that joins cannot be made on such fields.
Solution: change the field type from Long String to Short String.

Always use Number (AutoNumber) or GUID for IDs.

One of these id fields should be autonumber and the other should be long integer. What is relationship of these tables? Which is master and which is dependent?

I just imported 2 tab separated files as an independent msacess table. Also I have simplified the actual sourceid and file_id as numbers but in actuality they have the value like 20110112_195355_54 so I have fixed them as well as added the field type of each column. Also after changing sourceid and file_id to Short Text for both worked.

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

@KenWhite Noted and changed. Thanks for the tip.

SQL is correct. The error message is due to field type being a Long Text. Changing both and field type to Short Text should work.
SELECT Dev.sourceid, Dev.language, AudioInfo.file_id FROM Dev
INNER JOIN AudioInfo ON Dev.sourceid = AudioInfo.file_id;

The actual credit should go to Zaider and JoshuaG m(__)m
From Microsoft page, The Memo data type is now called “Long Text”. If that is so, then I wish they also change the error message from:

Cannot join on Memo, OLE, or Hyperlink Object ... toCannot join on Long Text, OLE, or Hyperlink Object ...
Changing field to Memo or OLE datatype requires removal of the specified index toChanging field to Long Text or OLE datatype requires removal of the specified index

